# FormGroup and FormControl cannot be found no matter what I do

Tags: angular

I am simply building a form that takes inputs within a dialog window. I import FormsModule, ReactiveFormsModule, FormBuilder, Validators, FormGroup, and FormControl in the app module. When that is done, I got an error. When I import those modules directly into my component, I get another error.

Here is my component with those modules directly imported ...

```
import { Component, OnInit, Inject, ViewEncapsulation } from '@angular/core';
import { MatDialog, MatDialogRef, MAT_DIALOG_DATA } from '@angular/material/dialog';
import { UserData } from 'app/main/profile/profile.component';
import { FormsModule, ReactiveFormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { FormBuilder, Validators, FormGroup, FormControl } from '@angular/forms';

@Component({
  selector: 'edit-bio-dialog',
  templateUrl: './edit-dialog.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./edit-dialog.component.scss'],
  encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.None
})
export class EditBioDialog implements OnInit {

    bioForm = new FormGroup({
        'gender'        : new FormControl(),
        'birth-month'   : new FormControl(),
        'birth-date'    : new FormControl(),
        'birth-year'    : new FormControl(),
        'about'         : new FormControl()
    });

    constructor(
        public dialogRef: MatDialogRef<EditBioDialog>,
        @Inject(MAT_DIALOG_DATA) public data: UserData) {
    }

    onNoClick(): void {
        this.dialogRef.close({data:this.data});
    }

    ngOnInit(): void {
    }

}
```

Doing this gives me the errors ...

```
error TS2304: Cannot find name 'FormGroup'
error TS2304: Cannot find name 'FormControl'
```

When I directly import the ReactiveFormsModule and others into the component (as well as into the app module) I get the errors ...

```
Error NG6002: Appears in the NgModule.imports of AppModule, but could not be resolved to an NgModule class
```

For both the Group and the Control.

What is the issue here? This should be incredibly simply and yet I cannot get Angular to recognize the Group and Control.

Comment: It would help if you showed the entire component file, including the imports at the top. And also you should show your App Module file.

Comment: I added the full component with the forms items imported

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your EditorBioDialog should only have `import { FormBuilder, FormGroup, Validators, FormControl } from '@angular/forms';` importing ReactiveFormsModule and FormsModule must be removed

While the app.module must import `ReactiveFormsModule` like below

app.module.ts

```
import { ReactiveFormsModule } from '@angular/forms';

@NgModule({
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    ReactiveFormsModule
  ],
  declarations: [
    //your components
  ],
  bootstrap: [//components]
})
```

Note: FormsModule is for template driven approach

Comment: So, why is this?

Comment: @JoshuaFoxworth in simple terms, app module is the root module of the application where it describes what are the components, modules, services, pipes, etc... that will be used in the application. `FormBuilder, FormGroup, Validators, FormControl`, these are packaged inside the module called, `ReactiveFormsModule`. Therefore, that module must be imported to our application before we use it. The module that includes `ReactiveFormsModule` will not be the app.module all the time it will differ per the application architecture. For more details refere, https://angular.io/guide/ngmodules

Answer (score 0):

In your App module you should import the modules, and also it is important that your component is a part of the same module, so something like:

`imports: [ Forms Module, ReactiveFormsModule], 
declarations: [ EditBioDialog ]`

Importing the FormsModule and ReactiveFormsModule at the top of your component file is not necessary. And importing FormBuilder, Validators, FormGroup and FormControl in your Module file is also not necessary.